# What does "one away from" ("two away from", etc) mean?

Tags: american-english

If you are one person away from someone in line, are you next to them or is there someone between you?

If there is a red rose two away from a yellow rose in a row, are there two roses between the red rose and the yellow rose or one rose between them?

Comment: This post [looks like this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378123/how-many-cars-behind), only it was cars  not roses.

Comment: Cascabel's link seems to have died.

Comment: Almost certainly, "one away from" is the same as "next in line to…" although there might be a difference there between US American and British English. 

Why can you not find a much more natural example than that rose scenario?

Is it obvious that "one behind…" must mean next in line?

That being so, can you explain why "one away from" should mean something different?